# How do I know if I misspeld a Maven property in the command line?

Tags: maven

For example, when I run:

```
C:\_SVN\myCode>mvn clean test -Dtest=TestSomething -Ddfkasfjkasdjffkjweijfijaskdf=false
```

the Maven build just does its thing as usual, gives me the same results as if I had made no mispelling at all (AFAICT).

Is there a way to get confirmation that I spelled the property name correctly (or at least input something valid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking about 2 solutions here:

1. mvn is just a script, which runs some maven jars. You might add some code to the script, which will check your syntax.
2. You might create maven plugin, which will validate passed properties.

Answer (score 1):

nope there ain't. It's like creating a variable that never used.